# Erro ao encerrar Lib()

Tags: python, sip, voip

Estou fazendo uma implementação da lib pjsua para trabalhar com VoIP utilizando python.

```
from datetime import datetime
from time import sleep
from sys import exit

from pysip.callbacks import AbstractCallCallback, AbstractAccountCallback
from pysip.states import CallState, MediaState
from pysip import Worker, GenericError

now = (lambda: datetime.now().strftime("%H:%M:%S.%f"))
class AccountCallback(AbstractAccountCallback):
    def on_incoming_call(self, call):
        callid = call.info().sip_call_id
        print(f'{now} - {callid} - Nova chamada recebida.')
        call.answer(486, "Busy")

class CallCallback(AbstractCallCallback):
    def on_state(self):
        info = self.call.info()
        callid = info.sip_call_id
        if info.state == CallState.DISCONNECTED:
            print(f'{now()} - {callid} - Chamada finalizada.')
        else:
            print(f'{now()} - {callid} - Estado alterado. Novo estado: {info.state_text}')
            print(f'{now()} - {callid} - Sinalzação: {info.last_code} {info.last_reason}')

    def on_media_state(self):
        info = self.call.info()
        callid = info.sip_call_id
        if info.media_state == MediaState.ACTIVE:
            Worker.instance().conf_connect(info.conf_slot, 0)
            Worker.instance().conf_connect(0, info.conf_slot)
            print(f'{now()} - {callid} - Mídia ativada.')
        else:
            print(f'{now()} - {callid} - Mídia desativada.')

def make_call(acc, destiny):
    worker = Worker(logfile='registros.log')
    with worker as runner:
        account_cb = CallCallback()
        account = runner.make_account(**acc)
        call = account.make_call(dst_uri=destiny, cb=account_cb)
        callid = call.info().sip_call_id
        sleep(5)
        call.hangup()

    return call.info().sip_call_id
if __name__ == '__main__':
    destiny = 'sip:1001@development.com'
    acc = {'username': '1000',
            'domain': 'development',
            'password': '1000',
            'callback': AccountCallback}
    try:
        callid = make_call(acc, destiny)
        print(f'Chamada realizada: {callid}') 
    except GenericError as error:
        print(error)
```

[Neste código](https://github.com/Otoru/pysip/blob/master/examples/call.py) Consegui gerar uma ligação completa e inclusive fazer a troca de áudio, mas após os N segundos de sleep do código, a chamada é encerrada conforme solicitado, todavia, o script não é encerrado e o python permanece trancado até que eu mate o processo em outra aba do terminal.

Todo código utilizado está no repositório acima citado. Preferi linkar o código a postar aqui, pois em vez de um bloco isolado, lá é possível ver o script como um todo.

Comment: Se o código de exemplo da biblioteca está travando, é bem provável que seja um bug na biblioteca - talvez seja o caso de abrir um issue no github da biblioteca

Comment: Gostaria muito de fazer isso, mas eles não possuem repositório oficial.
De qualquer forma agradeço a dica, realmente o faria caso pudesse.

Comment: Voltando nesta pergunta hoje Vitor, só agora entendi - a pergunta está confusa devido justamente ao código linkado. Achei que você era usuário da lib, só agora percebi que o repositório é seu - você é o autor da lib `pysip` feita em cima do `pjsua`... Para clarificar a pergunta, sugiro fazer um pequeno exemplo de conexão mínimo usando somente `pjsua` que reproduza o problema, ou seja, um **[MCVE](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)**.

Comment: Opa, Boa ideia. Vou fazer isso e anexar o código nessa pergunta.